# Trouble with fscanf() in c programming

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read some data in a file called "data" with specific format. The data in this file is:

```
0 mpi_write() 100
1 mpi_write() 200
2 mpi_write() 300
4 mpi_write() 400
5 mpi_write() 1000
```

then code is as follow:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct tracetype{
    int pid;
    char* operation;
    int size;
}tracetyper;

void main(){
    FILE* file1;
    file1=fopen("./data","r");
    if(file1==NULL){
        printf("cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        tracetyper* t=(tracetyper*)malloc(sizeof(tracetyper));
        while(feof(file1)!=EOF){
            fscanf(file1,"%d %s %d\n",&t->pid,t->operation,&t->size);

            printf("pid:%d,operation:%s,size:%d",t->pid,t->operation,t->size);
        }
        free(t);
    }
    fclose(file1);
}
```

When running with gdb, I found fscanf doesn't write data to t->pid,t->operation and t->size. Any thing wrong with my code or what? Please help me!

Comment: also, I found there may be not correct to use feof() in while loop because when running this program, it NEVER ends. Any comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior: you are reading `%s` data into an uninitialized `char*` pointer. You need to either allocate `operation` with `malloc`, or if you know the max length is, say, 20 characters, you can put a fixed string for it into the struct itself:

```
typedef struct tracetype{
    int pid;
    char operation[21]; // +1 for null terminator
    int size;
} tracetyper;
```

When you read `%s` data, you should always tell `fscanf` the limit on the length, like this:

```
fscanf(file1,"%d %20s %d\n",&t->pid,t->operation,&t->size);
```

Finally, you should remove `\n` at the end of the string, and check the count of returned values instead of checking `feof`, like this:

```
for (;;) { // Infinite loop
    ...
    if (fscanf(file1,"%d %20s %d",&t->pid,t->operation,&t->size) != 3) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: it does not hurt to be conservative with with '%20s'. But if the string is longer than the expected 20 you need to take alternative action (to a least throw away the extra). Otherwise the following %d is going to get the wrong value (and the result may still be 3).

Comment: @LokiAstari Right, this is just the most basic setup, which assumes a reasonably controlled environment (i.e. an ability to fix the file if the format is wrong). A real production code with files coming from uncontrolled environments will be more complex.

Comment: Really help. Appreciate!

Answer (score -1):

You should loop with something like:

```
while ( (fscanf(file1,"%d %s %d\n",&t->pid,t->operation,&t->size)) != EOF) {
   printf("pid:%d,operation:%s,size:%d",t->pid,t->operation,t->size);
}
```

You also need to add malloc for char array in the structure.
Also, insert a check for `t` as

```
if (t == NULL)
   cleanup();
```